# Android Restart Loader in a thread

Tags: android, loader, android-handler, connection-timeout

I'm using Loaders in my android App to retrieve data from the web. in my onCreate() method I initialize the loader. Once the data is retrieved, I can access them in onLoadFinished() method. This is working fine.

I'm trying to add a time-out so that if the request takes more than 15 seconds, I destroy the loader and re-initiate it. I'm using the following to achieve this:

```
    private void timeOutTimer()
   {
    final Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {


            myHandler.post(recreateLoader);

            t.cancel();
        }
    }, 15000);
}

final Runnable recreateLoader = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

            if(getLoaderManager().getLoader(MY_LOADER) != null || getLoaderManager().getLoader(MY_LOADER) != null)
            {



            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Reconnecting..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(MY_LOADER);
                ReInitiateLoader();



            }


            }
    }
};
```

The problem is that onLoadFinished is never called. It seems that initiating the Loader in a thread doesn't work. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: sure,  use a Handler

Comment: @pskink but am using a handler "myHandler.post(recreateLoader);"
or how do you mean exactly to use it?

Comment: use only Handler,  without Timer

Comment: @pskink you mean something like this?

                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {


                            }
                        }, 15000);

what's the difference?

Comment: yes,  your code posts on unknown Handler myHandler, i dont kniw what Looper it uses,  now you ate sure you call everything in the UI thread and the code is much simpler

Comment: @pskink it's working! however onCreate() method is called again. Can I avoid this?

Comment: Activity.onCreate ? how come?  when?